# Fullcalendar not displaying when in a template file

Tags: jquery, angularjs, calendar, fullcalendar

I was trying to use full calendar to have a nicer looking calendar than Google on my website. I followed all of the steps to put it on there, and it works for the index page. But once I try to put it in the calendar template page which is controlled using angular, it won't display.

Calendar template:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="box">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <hr>
        <h2 class="intro-text text-center">Our <strong>Events</strong>
        <center>
            <img style="width:110px;" class="img-responsive" src="img/hammerandtongs.png" alt="">
        </center>
        </h2>
        <hr>
        <div id="calendar"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Would I have to write a controller to get the calendar to display, or am I missing something entirely?

Comment: you're using angular? I have a plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Sx5ECU)

Comment: `<center>` tag is beyond deprecated. It is classified as a ["non-conforming feature"](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/center). `<font face="Comic Sans">`Don't use it!`</font>`

Comment: @calebboyd, amazing plunker! `getRandomEvents()` is totally neat :)